# Proving $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am stuck on proving this and I do not know how I should go about doing so algebraically.

$$\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$$

Comment: What is $P$?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: P refers to a power set

Comment: Hint: $x\in (A\cap B)\implies x\in (A\cup B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$. By definition, $X \subseteq A \cap B$. So $X \subseteq A$ and $X \subseteq B$. This means that $X \subseteq A \cup B$. Then $X \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$. Therefore $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$. $\square$

Comment: Wouldn't we need to prove it the same way for the Right Hand Side?

Comment: No, because we only want to prove that the left hand set is a subset of the right hand set. You only need to prove for both sides if you want to prove that the two sets are equal to each other.

Answer (score 2):

If $M \in P(A \cap B)$, then $ M \subseteq A \cap B.$ Since $A \cap B \subseteq A \cup B,$ we get $ M \subseteq A \cup B.$ Thus $M \in P(A \cup B)$.